# How to add support for angular into jshint?

Tags: angularjs, jshint

I'm using webstorm and have custom config files for both jshint and jscs, in jshint I've added this params:

**jshintrc:**

```
{
  "globals": {
    "jasmine": true,
    "angular": true,
    "browser": true,
    "element": true
  }
}
```

But it still keeps highlighting angular and everything angular related.

How can I finally enable it?

Comment: You mean Webstorm is highlighting them. Nothing to do with JSHint. You need to add them to the project's *Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries*

Comment: I'm using JShint as a Code Quality tool and using my own config for it.

Comment: Yes, I know what it is but it's got nothing to do with what Webstorm does or does not highlight as a problem. Also, the correct value for ignoring globals is `false`, not `true`

Comment: Set the path of ``JShint.json`` file for  ``Custom Configuration file`` option under ``Settings-> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Code Quality  Tools -> JSHint`` and enable it by checking ``Enable`` checkbox option on the top

Comment: @SameerK I already did it for the ```.jshintrc``` file, there is no option to do so for the json file.

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of your configuration .